# Do spammer get banned immediatly from SE?

Tags: discussion

[This guy](https://askubuntu.com/users/288418/user288418) is a spammer, he answered a question and doesn't take a genius to see he's a spammer, I'm kinda impressed that spammers take the time to sign up. On Chess.SE they do anonymous edits. Bots.

Do spammers get banned immediately or do they get a second chance?

Comment: I think I got the answer, the account is removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

Spammers are destroyed on sight. SE has a very powerful spam system in place that helps make sure they don't come back, we just have to kick them the first time ;-)

If you see a spam user still alive, feel free to jump into chat and let someone know.